# TortoiseSVN External failed 'folder' is already locked via

Tags: svn, cordova, tortoisesvn

So I went through and re-organized my SVN repository structure (removed 2 levels of directories that were not necessary).

Once done, I noticed that my svn external links were lost, so I needed to re-add them.

My first attempt I actually created the svn external one folder to deep: (should have been ./www but was actually ./www/www) so I reverted those changes, did an update, etc.

Now, I created my svn externals correctly (so I think) the second time, I got them created like this: ./www and ./platforms/ios/www (by the way, this is a phonegap project if that makes a difference).

Once I got that done, i needed to commit my changes. When committing, it SVN said it wasn't update to date, so I did the update, then committed and it worked successfully. But when I was navigating through those external directories, I did an SVN Update just to make sure they matched the common directory that they come from and I am getting this error:

```
External failed: ....parent\www
Error '.....parent\www' is already locked via (it doesn't provide anything after via)
Error '....parent'
Error: Please execute the "cleanup" command

{duplicate the above for the second external location}
```

So, I've tried to execute the TortoiseSVN -> Clean up command, and that says it finished successfully, but my updates still throw the error.

Thoughts?

**Update:** I was able to make an insignificant change to one of the files under my svn:externals folder and it propogated to all locations without any issue, but as soon as I go back to the parent folder and do an update their, I continue to get my error (but all of the code is correct, with my changes).

I've blown away the directory on my local machine, done a checkout again. Also had a coworker do a checkout of this new repo on their own machine, and they all get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove all of the SVN:External references in my project. Then re-add them starting with the DEEPEST path first. As long as I did that order, everything was fine.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Still getting **already locked** error.